# WP8 ScheduledActionService - alarm delay

Tags: delay, alarm, windows-phone-8, scheduledactionservice

I'm getting a lot of reports about a problem with delayed notifications from people using my timer app on windows phone 8.

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/timer/38ac6043-0d3e-471a-9527-a20d1ef8521b

There was always the problem that Alarms added to the ScheduledActionService aren't very accurate. I fixed the problem when the app is running by adding and removing a dummy alarm shortly after the real alarm counted to 0. This "woke up" the ScheduledActionService, it checked for expired alarms and showed the notification. This behaviour changed with WP8.

My little hack doesn't work any more and a lot of people seems to be quiet frustrated about it. I also got feedback that sometimes the alarms don't work under the lockscreen at all. Sadly I can only reproduce the first problem on the emulator. Has anyone experienced similar behaviour?

Is there any other possibility to tell the ScheduledActionService to check it's alarms?

Is it possible to hide my app in the store on WP8 devices up to the time when I corrected this behaviour?

regards,

Christian

Comment: To Unpublish an app or hide it in market place, click on apps tab on the left of your WP dashboard and select the app. After that you should get the option to hide the app

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. I created a basic voice enabled timer app. The problem I had was if someone sets the alarm to go off in 20 seconds and I create that scheduled action well its not going to work for one minute.

"Alarms and Reminders are accurate only within a range of one minute. In other words, the notification can be launched up to one minute after it was scheduled." -msdn

I know you know this but I thought I would include it for others reading. I ended up initially creating all alarms via a timer in code and if the user exits the app only then do I create a scheduled action. If the user tries to close the app and there is less than one minute remaining I show a message box I don't remember the exact warning but its along the lines of the phone cannot show the alarm for one minute after exiting the application.

Maybe you could split the options up for the user?
an accurate timer that only works when the app is open and you can control in code down to the second, and a more generic timer that works outside of the app that would only allow one minute increments.

Comment: Your workaround sounds good. I already tried a version where I implemented a custom Alarm notification. Sadly this isn't as reliable as the ScheduledAlarm. The main problem was that it depends on the volume settings of the User. Did you find a way to work around this?

Comment: I like this we are having the same problems! No I didn't really just another work around. Vibrate.

Comment: I just re read my comment and realized it was too vague wasn't it? I'm a awful writer :) If it wasn't clear I use the phones vibrate to alert the user as well as a sound. They can turn the phone down but its harder for them to turn off vibrate and honestly at that point they must not want any audible alert :)